# Skip confirmation for known hosts?

Tags: mac, ssh, terminal

On my mac when I ssh to a known host I get:

```
Matching host key in /Users/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:5
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Why does it still warn me if it is a known host? It should only warn me if it is an unknown address. How can I skip it?

.ssh/config content:

```
Host s1
   Hostname myserver.website.com
   User user1
   GSSAPIAuthentication yes
   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
```

Comment: What is the content of your `.ssh/config`, for the relevant host you connect to (+ global options). Which version of `ssh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in your configuration `StrictHostKeyChecking yes`, as the question you get comes from a value of `ask` for this parameter (may be the default in your installation).

This comes from this part of the source code:

```c
    if (options.check_host_ip && host_status != HOST_CHANGED &&
        ip_status == HOST_CHANGED) {
            snprintf(msg, sizeof(msg),
                "Warning: the %s host key for '%.200s' "
                "differs from the key for the IP address '%.128s'"
                "\nOffending key for IP in %s:%lu",
                type, host, ip, ip_found->file, ip_found->line);
            if (host_status == HOST_OK) {
                    len = strlen(msg);
                    snprintf(msg + len, sizeof(msg) - len,
                        "\nMatching host key in %s:%lu",
                        host_found->file, host_found->line);
            }
            if (options.strict_host_key_checking ==
                SSH_STRICT_HOSTKEY_ASK) {
                    strlcat(msg, "\nAre you sure you want "
                        "to continue connecting (yes/no)? ", sizeof(msg));
                    if (!confirm(msg))
                            goto fail;
```

Which seems to mean basically that the host key did not change but its IP did change, so with the `ask` value the system wanted you to confirm in this case. But change of IP address can happen in normal life and should/could be ignored, if the host key still matches of course.

Side note:

Do not use `on` as it will not work, you need `yes` (`off` exists as alias to `no` but `on` does not exist), thanks to Kamil Maciorowski careful review.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  Agreed, and I just kept the part about the IP address and migrated it in the answer.